# a book recommendation for doing graphics in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, books

I am interested in drawing diagrams, trees, and other simple basic graphical items (all in [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer), as a matter of fact). Can someone recommend on a good book that would explain how to do that? (I am guessing the package of choice for doing this should be TikZ, so maybe I am looking for a good book about TikZ.)

I *think* I prefer to learn this "by example", but it does not have to be that kind of book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's the [`pgf manual`](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) with lots of examples and the [`Minimal introduction to TikZ`](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). Also, there's a really nice example gallery at [`TeXample.net`](http://texample.net/tikz/). And of course, browsing this site you will also find a good collection of examples.

Since you specifically mentioned trees, besides the `trees` library from TikZ, the [`tikz-qtree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) package could also be of interest for you (it uses TikZ and the `qtree` syntax).